# How to multiply one matrix by another in order to return a matrix of ones

Tags: matrix, octave

I have a 20x20 matrix filled with random numbers. I need to find what matrix will multiply with the random one in order to return a 20x1 matrix of all ones.

**What I've tried:**

`inv(A)` (where A is a 20x20 matrix filled with random numbers) I know I don't want the inverse of the matrix because, if successful, it would only return the identity matrix, which is not what I need.

Comment: I updated my answer to provide pointers to some MATLAB built-ins which can be used to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use matrix algebra to express the problem and derive the solution. Consider the following, where * means matrix multiplication and 1 means the vector of all ones, and Ainv is the inverse matrix for A.

```
A*x=1
Ainv * A * x = Ainv * 1
x = Ainv * 1
```

[EDIT 7 MAR 2016]

In many computer algebra systems (MATLAB, scipy, etc.), there is a function called `solve` (or similar) which can be used to solve linear systems expressed as Ax=b. In particular, for MATLAB, see: [linsolve](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linsolve.html). Also, for MATLAB, see the [backslash operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html).

I'm a python user, so I use `numpy.linalg.solve()`, which does the same thing (see this [link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html)).

Comment: That worked, thanks!!! I never even thought of writing out the algebra for it, I just assumed there was an octave specific way...haha